# How to get Maximum Difference between Dates in a row using SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, date, amazon-athena

| Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Date 4 | LineCount | Month_Gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2019-10-01 | 2019-09-06 |  | 1 |  |
| 2020-01-01 | 2019-10-01 | 2019-09-13 | 2019-09-06 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2019-10-01 | 2019-08-13 | 2019-09-06 | 2 | 1 |

If the `LineCount` is 1, then `Month_Gap` should be the maximum month difference between (Date1 & Date3) and (Date2 & Date3). Date3 will always be in between Date1 and Date2.

In this Case, the output should be the max month difference between (2020/01/01 - 2019/09/06) and (2019/10/01 - 2019/09/06), which is 3 months:

| Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Date 4 | LineCount | Month_Gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2019-10-01 | 2019-09-06 |  | 1 | 3 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2019-10-01 | 2019-09-13 | 2019-09-06 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2019-10-01 | 2019-08-13 | 2019-09-06 | 2 | 1 |

I was trying something like this but not sure how to go about it -
CASE WHEN `LineCount` = 1 THEN MAX(DATE_DIFF(.....), which won't work I guess.

Comment: tag your dbms name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN LineCount = 1 THEN GREATEST(DATE_DIFF('month', Date3, Date1), 
    DATE_DIFF('month', Date3, Date2)) END AS Month_Gap
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you should use is

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF("MONTH", LEAST(date1,date2,date3,date4), GREATEST(date1,date2,date3,date4)) as `maximum_difference`;
```

This will simply look through your columns, find the least and greatest, and return the result.